# "Abstraction" in the context of I/O system

Tags: java

I was reading **Java A Beginner’s Guide, Eighth Edition** book specifically in Chapter 10, Using I/O, and I read this phrase **"An I/O stream is an abstraction that either produces or consumes information"** I know about abstraction in the context of programming, but what is the meaning of the word abstraction here? I did not understand what it means!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *abstraction* here is used in the context of programming. Java's `java.io.InputStream` and `java.io.OutputStream` are interfaces which abstract away the underlying IO technology. When consuming such a stream instance, you do not have to care about where exactly the data comes from, you only use the Stream interface. The implementation could be an [in-memory stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html), a [file on disk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), a network request, an [audio stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html), etc.

When you (or your program) works with an input stream, it simply needs to call [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])), without worrying about the underlying technology. With output streams this becomes a simple call to [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[])).

Answer (score 0):

for example abstraction is used on a button on telephone. You use button to do activity, but you dont know how it works. It just do the job.

Here, it means you can use I/O stream for produce or consume information without wondering how it works. You just can use its already written methods.